# ¿How can I add a 'load more' button during asynchronous searching?

Tags: javascript, search, asynchronous

I have this little problem... when I search anything on my website the results are showed asynchronously while typing... solo if The word that I'm asking for has something like I don't know... 100 results, all the results will appear and the page's scroll will be too long, so I need some button that allows me to load the results 10 by 10 (or something like that)

here's the code I've done so far...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="busqueda"  name="busqueda" value="" required autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="search();">
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="loadmore" hidden="hidden" name="loadmore"> load more</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var track_page = 1; //track user click as page number, righ now page number 1
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
require('db_conexion.php');

$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];


if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
  exit();
}
//capacity
$item_per_page = 5;

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

//query
$buscar= $conexion->query("SELECT info from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position,$item_per_page");

//conditionals
    if (!$query_execute->num_rows) {
        $mensaje = "no results";
    }else{
        $filas= $query_execute->num_rows;
        echo $filas.' Results for <mark>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</mark>';

//show results 
while($row = $buscar->fetch_array()) {

            $variables="something";      
            echo $variables;
        }
    } 
}else{
echo "Error";
}    
?>
```

JS:

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {return false;}
}
document.onkeypress = stopRKey;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#result").html('<p> </p>');
    var track_page = 1; //track user click as page number, righ now page number 1
});

function search() {
     var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $("#result").show();
        $(".close").show();
        $("#loadmore").show();
        $.post("actions/buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda, 'page': track_page}, function(mensaje) {
              if(mensaje.trim().length == 0){
       $("#loadmore").hide();
      //display text and disable load button if nothing to load
      $("#loadmore").text("No hay mas resultados que mostrar").prop("disabled", true);
    }
      //load the result
      $("#result").html(mensaje);
        //scroll page to button element
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#loadmore").offset().bottom}, 100);

         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#loadmore").hide();
        $(".close").hide();
        $("#result").html('<p> </p>');
        };

     //load more results
     $("#loadmore").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button
     track_page++; //page number increment everytime user clicks load button
     search(track_page);
});
};
```

but I couldn't make it work properly yet... because ok; I search for something, I got the first 10 results but then... when I click on the 'load more' button, I got the old ten results replaced by the next ones and not the 20 results in order as it should be, so...

Hope you could help me guys :C

Answer (score 1):

You always place result into `#result`, erasing `#result` content.
You may:

- append results: `$('#result').append(mensage)` or `$('#result')[0].innerHTML+=mensage` or `$('<div>').html(mebsaje).appendTo('#result')`
- prepend results: `$('<div class=".result">').html(mebsaje).insertBefore('#result')` (`#result` will be always after the last one)
- move id: `$("#result").html(mensaje).removeAttr('id').addClass('.result').after('<div id="result">')`

Comment: um you seem to be close.. I made the changes but it's not working properly yet, you can check it out on this link   http://www.subeuna.com/blog/  ... search the letter 'a' for example, and try to load more results, you'll see how is actually working and its not ok u.u